# ¿Es una ofensa llamar a alguien "ese"?

Tags: diferencias-regionales

> Orale, ese, qué pasa?

¿Es una ofensa le llamar a alguien "ese" ? En la película " Sangre por Sangre" acostumbran llamarse mutuamente "ese". ¿Sería una ofensa llamar a alguien "ese", si no fueras mexicano?

Comment: En el español de España nunca se utiliza "ése" como segunda persona, así que la frase "Hola, ése, ¿qué pasa?" nunca se diría.

Comment: Quiero comentar que hasta hace bien poco, la escritura correcta sería "ése", con acento, porque es un pronombre. Aunque ahora se permite escribir los pronombres sin acento, la mayoría de la gente que escribe suele preferir usarlo de todas formas.

Comment: Realmente, se permite escribirlo sin acento desde hace, al menos, cincuenta años (la RAE en sus escritos oficiales nunca lo ponía). Hoy día lo que ha hecho la RAE es recomendar no usar la tilde diacrítica en los demostrativos y en el adjetivo/advervio *solo*, aunque siguen estando permitidas ambas formas.

Comment: si estan los animos muy caldeados si puede sonar a una ofensa, ese y esa

Comment: also in the movie "American me" you hear this a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para mí la forma que usan "*ese*" en esa película es más en referencia a la cultura de pandillas. Nosotros, entre amigos, cuando queríamos molestar a alguien le decíamos *¿qué pasa ese fecal?*.

En Guatemala es una ofensa llamar a alguien *ese*, en esta ocasión se refiere a una tercera persona. Cuando dices, *¿cómo se llama "ese"?*, la respuesta general es: "esa es una persona, así que refiérase a él o ella con el subjetivo correcto". Se ve y escucha mal decir "ese" o "esa". Es mejor decir como se llama él o ella.

Comment: Para aclarar: "¿qué pasa ese fecal?" significa en la cultura de pandillas, según entiendo, "¿qué te ocurre, _hez_ fecal?"

Answer (score 5):

Donde yo crecí, en Los Angeles, California, "ese" no tiene malas conotaciones entre amigos. Es equivalente a la palabra "dude" en inglés.  Nunca se usa para referirse a una persona de mayor estatus como la familia o un jefe.  Solo entre amigos se usa así.

Cuando la gente no chicana la usan para referirse a la gente chicana o latina, se puede interpretar como insulto, dependiendo de la familiaridad entre el que la usa y a quien se refiere.

Answer (score 5):

Siguiendo el contexto de la película que mencionas, "Sangre por sangre(blood in, blood out)", te puedo decir que es un término generado en la cultura chicana y mas específicamente en las pandillas mexicanas de California.

Inicialmente se llamaba a alguien `Ese` porque ésta es la pronunciación de la letra "S" que en éste particular uso se refería a los `Sureños`, que son una pandilla Mexicana perteneciente a la pandilla 13(`Sur 13`). De esta forma se hacía referencia a estos miembros de la pandilla y el término adquirió un significado similar al de `homie`, `homeboy`, `vato`, etc, lo cual sirve para expresar camaradería entre amigos cercanos(inicialmente miembros de dicha pandilla).

Actualmente se usa de manera general por chicanos y mexicanos gangsters "wannabe" que viven en California. El uso de dicho término en México es casi nulo y lo utilizan con este significado sólo algunos jóvenes que se quieren expresar como `cholos` o `chicanos`, ya sea porque han regresado a México después de haber vivido en Estados Unidos o bien porque quieren imitar el estilo de hablar de los pandilleros méxico-americanos.

Comment: +1 excelente explicación, es la respuesta correcta.

Answer (score 4):

Según yo, depende de la situación. Por ejemplo, si estás conversando con alguien y dices "*Es ese de ahí"* refiriendote a alguien que está a cierta distancia, no creo que se pueda tomar como ofensa, simplemente le estás indicando a esa persona.

También dependerá mucho del tono en mi opinión. Si dijieras la misma frase, "*Es ese de ahí"*, pero con tono de desprecio, podría considerarse de mala manera.

Pero, si llegaras a utilizar la misma frase, y la persona a la que te refieres te llega a escuchar, él/ella podría llegar a ofenderse.

Como dije, según mi opinión, todo dependería de la situación y del tono en que se diga.

Comment: Yo diría que es despectivo especialmente si el hablante conoce el nombre de la persona referida "Dile a ése que se vaya".

Comment: en mi caso he notado que las mujeres la usan mucho más para referirse a otra mujer en tono despectivo... esa p...!!!

Answer (score 4):

En Colombia referirse a una persona,  como **ese** es peyorativo.  Se hace en un contexto agresivo,  y es claramente una demostracion de desprecio.

Answer (score -1):

Yo creo que depende del contexto. Si se enfatiza la palabra, suena ofensivo, sí.